# Can I loop puppet until a condition is met?

Tags: puppet

I am quite new to puppet and I want to execute a command (let's call it command1) only when a HTTP server is up and running in another host. I am 100% sure that the server will get ready, so I want to create a loop which checks for port 80 in the remote ip (for example using netcat: nc -zv remote_ip 80) and it just iterates until it succeeds checking and then it executes command1. Is this possible?

Comment: Puppet Enterprise or not?

Comment: Not, opensource

Comment: If you were using Enterprise, then Puppet Orchestrator could do this for you. You will need to wrap Puppet inside something else to do this in one inter-host execution. With multiple executions, you can do this with exported/virtual resources or MCollective.

Comment: You can write an `Exec` resource that does your polling, And a separate one to run your desired command.  An appropriate relationship set up between the two will ensure that the first is applied successfully before (and as a condition of) the second being applied.